# как загрузить картинку через input

Tags: javascript, файлы, input

Вот мой код:

```
<body>
<input type="file" id="file1" />
<img src="" id="image1" width="500px" height="500px" />
<button onclick="save()">Save</button>
<script>
  function save() {
    document.getElementById("image1").src = document.getElementById("file1").value;
  }
</script>
```

Как сделать так что бы выбранная картинка пользователем, загрузилась в `img` и реализовать это с помощью javascript. Я в этом новичок, пробовала искать в интернете но варианты не подошли. Буду благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, Вам нужен `URL.createObjectURL` :

```html
<input type="file" id="file1" />
<button onclick="save()">Save</button>
<img id="image1" width="500px" height="500px" />
<br>
<script>
    
    function save ()  {
        let f = file1.files[0];
        if (f) {
            image1.src = URL.createObjectURL(f);
            localStorage.setItem('myImage', image1.src);
        }
    }
    
    image1.src = localStorage.getItem('myImage')
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что я хотела, а можно ли это как-то реализовать на мобильном устройстве? Я протестировала и поняла что на мобильном устройстве файлы вообще не окрываються.

Comment: @ElviraKukhtaruk подкрутил ответ

Comment: можно ли как-то сохранить её с помощью localstorage?

Comment: @ElviraKukhtaruk в целом да, в виде строки, которая вернется из `URL.createObjectURL`

Comment: Я сделала следущее: localStorage.setItem("myImage", file1.value); и извлекла значение, но когда перезагружаю страницу, картинка пропадает...

Comment: @ElviraKukhtaruk а восстанавливали как?

Comment: я только сохронила и извлекла...

Comment: вот  я добавила это вне функции  image1.src = localStorage.getItem("myImage"); В хранилище оно сохранилось даже после закрытия страницы, а на в img нет...

Comment: @ElviraKukhtaruk я дополнил ответ, однако в сниппете на so localStorage отключен, на всякий случай вот https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/WNeLGxW

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так

```js
document.getElementById('file1').addEventListener('change', function() {
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
      document.getElementById('image1').setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file1" />
<img src="" id="image1" width="500px" height="500px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще использовать объект URL. А показывать картинку сразу после выбора:

```js
let image = document.getElementById("image");
let file = document.getElementById("file");

file.addEventListener('change', function(){
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file.files[0]);
  image.style.display = "block";
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" />
<img src="" id="image" style="max-width: 600px; display: none;"/>
```